# Describe the partitions of the equivalence relations for the map $f:(x,y) \mapsto x$.

Tags: functions, equivalence-relations, projection

Question: Describe the partitions of the equivalence relations for the map:

$$f:(x,y) \mapsto x$$

I had a different question on my homework, but I'm not really sure what the question is asking, so maybe if I see the solution for this one example it would clarify things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a projection onto the x-axis, so the relation would be $(x_1,y_1) \sim
 (x_2,y_2) \iff x_1=x_2$. In other words, the plane is partitioned into vertical lines.

Comment: so are you saying that the equivalence is between points in the domain.... I'm not sure I understand, my question's range was actually (x,y) goes to x+y.  but i have a few other examples to do

Comment: Yes, the equivalence is on points in the domain. In your second example, the function determines an equivalence relation $(x_1,y_1) \sim (x_2,y_2) \iff x_1+y_1=x_2+y_2$. Do you know how to verify this is indeed an equivalence relation?

Comment: well another question was (x,y) to sqrt(x^2+y^2)... and I DO understand this one.  I can think of the equivalence classes as concentric circles in the plane.  But I don't see the one above.

Comment: Try fixing a number and plotting out the x's and y's that add to it. You should see it right away..

Comment: AH!  I see x+y now.... its just slashes through the plane in a top left to bottom right pattern.